# Select Distinct results from tow tables mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view

I have tow tables (MYSQL) contains different column names and want to query all the data from table 1 and all the data from table 2 which is not existing in table 1

the data is like:
Table 1

```
Ref     Desc    Price

A       TEXT1     12
B       TEXT2     10
C       TEXT3     5
```

Table 2:

```
Code     Desc    Price

A       TEXT1     7
B       TEXT2     10
D       TEXT4     2
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
Ref     Desc    Price

A       TEXT1     12
B       TEXT2     10
C       TEXT3     5
D       TEXT4     2
```

So i have tried to make this view:

```
CREATE  OR REPLACE VIEW `partsquery` AS
SELECT  table1.Ref AS reference,    
        table1.Desc AS description,
        table1.Price AS price
        FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT  t2.code AS Ref,
        t2.Desc AS description,
        t2.price  AS price
FROM
    table2 AS t2
    LEFT JOIN table1 AS t1
    ON 
            t2.Code = t1.Ref
WHERE t1.Ref Is Null;
```

this view gives me what i want but actually its to slow because i have big data. So is there another way to get my result ?!

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
union all
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.code = t2.code);
```

For performance, you want in index on `table1(code)`.

I cannot think of a faster way to run this query.

If you need this data quickly, you might need to create a second table, along with an trigger on the first two tables.  The trigger would insert new rows according to your conditions.  That will get rid of the `union all` and allow you to build indexes, at the cost of more code complexity and space usage.